# Show message with PHP when a parameter is passed in the URL

Tags: php, http, url

As new in PHP, I have a simple question. Am I able to do something like this?

E.g. the user, is redirected to a link like this:

http://website.com/directory?parameter

When that parameter is in the URL, I want a message to appear somewhere in the website, when the parameter is missing, just hide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get parameters are stored in the `$_GET` variable. So you can check if a get parameter is set with:

```
if(isset($_GET['parameter'])) {
    echo 'parameter is set';
}
else {
    echo 'parameter is not set';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a parameter like this:

```
http://site.com/page.php?this=that
```

You create what is called a [GET request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods). In order to echo what's in the request, you'd do:

```
<?php echo $_GET['this']; ?>
```

In this instance, this would output:

```
that
```

To read more about PHP superglobals like $_GET, [check out this link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Suppose this is URL http://site.com/page.php?url_var=val;
if(isset($_GET["url_var"]))
{
$msg = "your message";
}
else
{
$msg = "";
}

// NOW  JUST PRINT $MSG WHERE EVER YOU WANT WITH OUT ANY CONDITION;

echo $msg;
?>
```